# Loading scraped data into list

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I was able to successfully scrape some text from a website and I'm now trying to load the text into a list so I can later convert it to a Pandas DataFrame.

The site supplied the data in a scsv format so it was quick to grab.

#### The following is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Specify the url:url
url = "http://rotoguru1.com/cgi-bin/fyday.pl?week=1&year=2017&game=dk&scsv=1"

# Packages the request, send the request and catch the response: r
r = requests.get(url)

#Extract the response:html_doc
html_doc = r.text


soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc,"html.parser")

#Find the tags associated with the data you need, in this case
# it's the "pre" tags


for data in soup.find_all("pre"):
    print(data.text)
```

#### Sample Output

> Week;Year;GID;Name;Pos;Team;h/a;Oppt;DK points;DK salary
>   1;2017;1254;Smith, Alex;QB;kan;a;nwe;34.02;5400 1;2017;1344;Bradford,
>   Sam;QB;min;h;nor;28.54;5900

Comment: The code does not run for me

Comment: Apologies for that, I'm not sure what could have gone wrong. I'm running Python 3.6. I can copy and paste that exact code into my IDE and it runs.

Comment: No worries, what IDE are you using?

Comment: I'm using Spyder, the version that came with the latest Anaconda distribution.

Comment: I am using Spyder as well. The code runs but has no output.

Comment: When I enter just that url in my browser I get a 404 error. (Doesn't exist.) Are you quite sure that url is correct? Just did it for a 2nd time as check on my sanity.

Comment: I made a typo when I was copying and pasting into question editor. I just updated the code and saved those changes. This code should now run and produce an output.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one thing you can do, although it's possible that someone who knows pandas better than I can suggest something better.

You have `r.text`. Put that into a convenient text file, let me call it `temp.csv`. Now you can use `pandas read_csv` method to get these data into a dataframe.

```
>>> df = pandas.read_csv('temp.csv', sep=';')
```

Addendum:

Suppose `results` were like this.

```
>>> results = [['a', 'b', 'c'], [1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
```

Then you could put them in a dataframe in this way.

```
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame(results[1:], columns=results[0])
>>> df
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Bill. I did consider that. I was hoping to save the results as a list, then convert the list to a DataFrame. Currently the code is returning <class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'> instead of a list and I'm trying to figure out how to fix that piece.

Comment: OK, Brian. Do you simply mean that each line should become a list whose elements are the pieces that were originally separated by semicolons?

Comment: You might also want numeric items in the lists converted from strings to their numeric values ...

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I mean. I'm assuming I'll need to create a variable that holds an empty list, then write a loop that will iterate over each line and append it as a new row.

Comment: Yes, replace that very last line with, say, `results.extend(data.text.split(';'))`, having put `results=[]` just before the for-loop. That would give you a list of lists.

Comment: That worked. The trouble now is that when I convert it to a DataFrame using `df = pd.DataFrame(results)` i'm getting a DataFrame with 1 column x 3,592 rows. Any suggestions on what I could to unpivot this?

Comment: Please see addendum to answer.

Answer (score 0):

## use open function to write csv file

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://rotoguru1.com/cgi-bin/fyday.pl?week=1&year=2017&game=dk&scsv=1"
r = requests.get(url)
html_doc = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc,"html.parser")
file = open(“data.csv”,”w”)
for data in soup.find("pre").text.split('\n'):
    file.write(data.replace(';',','))
file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

If u want to convert your existing code into list, using split method  might do the job and then use pandas to convert it into dataframe.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Specify the url:url
url = "http://rotoguru1.com/cgi-bin/fyday.pl?week=1&year=2017&game=dk&scsv=1"

# Packages the request, send the request and catch the response: r
r = requests.get(url)

#Extract the response:html_doc
html_doc = r.text


soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc,"html.parser")

#Find the tags associated with the data you need, in this case
# it's the "pre" tags


for data in soup.find_all("pre"):
    print(data.text.split(";"))
```